# Mat-table make 3 columns expand and 1 column (click)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an Angular Material Table and I'm wanting to make the left column (Blue/LP) have a click event that will pass the LP into it. I'm wanting the right column to trigger an expand. I have it working right now to expand across the entire row. How can I target certain columns with different actions?

[image]

HTML:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column.name}}" *ngFor="let column of initColumns">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column.display}} </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column.name]}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="columnsToDisplay.length">
        <div class="example-element-detail" [@detailExpand]="element.expanded ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
          <table class="detail-table">
            <tr>
              <th>Weight</th>
              <th>Cube</th>
              <th>Zone</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>{{element.LPWeight}}</td>
              <td>{{element.LPCube}}</td>
              <td>{{element.Zone}}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay;" class="example-element-row"
      [class.example-expanded-row]="element.expanded" (click)="toggleRow(element)">
    </tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="example-detail-row"></tr>
  </table>
```

.TS

```
import { animate, state, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadinfoService } from 'src/app/services/loadinfo.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-lpstoload',
  templateUrl: './lpstoload.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lpstoload.page.scss'], animations: [
    trigger('detailExpand', [
      state('collapsed', style({ height: '0px', minHeight: '0' })),
      state('expanded', style({ height: '*' })),
      transition('expanded <=> collapsed', animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)')),
    ]),
  ],

})

export class LpstoloadPage implements OnInit {
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
  initColumns: any[] = [
    {
      name: 'LP',
      display: 'LP'
    },
    {
      name: 'SourceZone',
      display: 'Source'
    },
    {
      name: 'StopNumber',
      display: 'Stop'
    },
    {
      name: 'CaseCount',
      display: 'Cases'
    }
  ];
  displayedColumns: any[] = this.initColumns.map(col => col.name);
  columnsToDisplay = ['LP', 'SourceZone', 'StopNumber', 'CaseCount'];
  expandedElement: PeriodicElement | null;
  private lpsToLoad: any;
  constructor(private loadInfoService: LoadinfoService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    //this.lpsToLoad = this.loadInfoService.loadSummary.LPsToLoad;
  }

  toggleRow(element: { expanded: boolean; }) {
    element.expanded = !element.expanded
  }
}

export interface PeriodicElement {
  SG: string;
  LP: string;
  Status: String;
  Zone: string;
  SourceZone: string;
  StopNumber: string;
  CaseCount: number;
  LPWeight: number;
  LPCube: number;
  DBName: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {
    "SG": "",
    "LP": "00006844763848356453",
    "Status": "STAGED",
    "Zone": "SSTG",
    "SourceZone": "DRYF",
    "StopNumber": "4",
    "CaseCount": 120.0,
    "LPWeight": 480.0,
    "LPCube": 69.859573364257813,
    "DBName": "IL_DRY-WMS"
  },
  {
    "SG": "",
    "LP": "00006844763871917089",
    "Status": "STAGED",
    "Zone": "SSTG",
    "SourceZone": "DRYF",
    "StopNumber": "4",
    "CaseCount": 27.0,
    "LPWeight": 391.5,
    "LPCube": 95.586883544921875,
    "DBName": "IL_DRY-WMS"
  },
  {
    "SG": "",
    "LP": "00006844763892120215",
    "Status": "STAGED",
    "Zone": "SSTG",
    "SourceZone": "D-LT",
    "StopNumber": "4",
    "CaseCount": 88.0,
    "LPWeight": 510.39199829101563,
    "LPCube": 67.747936964035034,
    "DBName": "IL_DRY-WMS"
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

taking a shot in the dark here, but I think one thing you could do is divide one table row into 2 separate columns within the row and have a mouseover (or whatever event trigger your want) event from one column trigger the other column's action.  on column you can use an *ngIf boolean to have an overlay (or whatever element you want)..

you might want to consider not using mat-table and instead use a custom directive with with rows being generated as if it were a table so you can have total customisation without it turning into a mess.